$E(a, b) \pm F(a, b)$ Elliptic integral identity
I found this addition theorem of $F$ and $E$ on Wikipedia, but there’s no addition theorem that combines $F$ and $E$ together specifically
$$F\bigl[\arctan(x),k\bigr] + F\bigl[\arctan(y),k\bigr] = F\left[\arctan\left(\frac{x\sqrt{k'^2y^2+1}}{\sqrt{y^2+1}}\right) + \arctan\left(\frac{y\sqrt{k'^2x^2+1}}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\right),k\right]$$
$$E{\left[\arctan(x), k\right]}
 + E{\left[\arctan(y), k\right]}
= E{\left[\arctan\left(\frac{x\sqrt{k'^2y^2+1}}{\sqrt{y^2+1}}\right) + \arctan\left(\frac{y\sqrt{k'^2x^2+1}}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\right),k\right]}
 + \frac{k^2xy}{k'^2x^2y^2+x^2+y^2+1}\left(\frac{x\sqrt{k'^2y^2+1}}{\sqrt{y^2+1}}+\frac{y\sqrt{k'^2x^2+1}}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\right)$$
Since I’m interested in an addition or difference formula for $F$ and $E$
\begin{align}
E(a, b) \pm F(a, b) = E(\color{blue}{\,..},b)\lor \,F(\color{red}{..},b) + \cdots\\
\end{align}
I’ll work to get the different here because I think it might probably be simpler, but my question is concern with both
\begin{align}
F(a,b)+F(c,b) = F(d,b)\\
E(a,b)+E(c,b) = E(d,b)+e\\
\end{align}
let $a,b,c,d,e$ represents their respective functions written above, subtract both equations
\begin{align}
F(a,b)+F(c,b)-E(a,b)-E(c,b)= F(d,b)-E(d,b)-e\\
F(a,b)-E(a,b)+F(c,b)-E(c,b)= F(d,b)-E(d,b)-e\\
F(d,b)-E(d,b) = F(a,b)-E(a,b)+F(c,b)-E(c,b)+e\\
\end{align}
Since $a,b,c,d,e \in {x,y,k}$ so I can make one of the variable $x$ or $y$ ( upper limits ) to make both $F$ or both $E$ disappear from the RHS $\require{cancel}$
$$F(d,b)-E(d,b) = F(a,b)-\cancel{E(a,b)}+F(c,b)-\cancel{E(c,b)}+e$$
$$F(d,b)-E(d,b) = \cancel{F(a,b)}-E(a,b)+\cancel{F(c,b)}-E(c,b)+e$$
To make $F$ or $E$ disappear means I’m equating their upper limit to be zero, but $a$ is present in both $F$ and $E$, and $c$ is present in both $F$ and $E$
$$F(d,b)-E(d,b) = F(a,b)-E(a,b)+\cancel{F(c,b)}-\cancel{E(c,b)}+e$$
This shows the shape of the formula I’ll get from this method ( if it works ), it is recursive and more complicated, that’s why I’m asking if there’s any way at all to achieve this identity
Where $F$ combines with $E$ to become elementary function plus $F$ or $E$ but not both
Note: $F$ and $E$ are the incomplete elliptic integral of first kind and second kind
$$E(a, b) = \int_0^a \sqrt{\frac{1 - b^2 x^2}{1 - x^2}} \, dx$$
$$F(a, b) = \int_0^a \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(1 - x^2)(1 - b^2 x^2)}}$$
I tried working from their direct integral, to simplify $E(a, b) - F(a, b)$
$$E(a, b) - F(a, b) = \int_0^a \sqrt{\frac{1 - b^2 x^2}{1 - x^2}} \, dx - \int_0^a \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(1 - x^2)(1 - b^2 x^2)}}$$
$$E(a, b) - F(a, b) = \int_0^a \left( \sqrt{\frac{1 - b^2 x^2}{1 - x^2}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1 - x^2)(1 - b^2 x^2)}} \right) dx$$
I simplified the term inside the parentheses then got stuck
$$\sqrt{\frac{1 - b^2 x^2}{1 - x^2}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1 - x^2)(1 - b^2 x^2)}} =\frac{-b^2 x^2}{\sqrt{(1 - x^2)(1 - b^2 x^2)}}$$
$$E(a, b) - F(a, b) = \int_0^a \frac{-b^2 x^2}{\sqrt{(1 - x^2)(1 - b^2 x^2)}} \, dx$$

Let $x=\sin(t)$

I wonder if you are not looping in circles.
$$I=\int \frac{-b^2 x^2}{\sqrt{(1 - x^2)(1 - b^2 x^2)}} \, dx$$
$$x=\sin(t)\quad \implies \quad I=\int\frac{-b^2 \sin ^2(t) \cos(t)}{\sqrt{\cos^2(t) \left(1-b^2 \sin ^2(t)\right)}}\,dt$$
Assuming that $\sqrt{\cos^2(t)}=\cos(t)$
$$I=\int \frac {\Big(1-b^2 \sin ^2(t)\Big)-1 }{\sqrt{1-b^2 \sin ^2(t)}}\,dt=\int \sqrt{1-b^2 \sin ^2(t)}\,dt-\int\frac {dt}{\sqrt{1-b^2 \sin ^2(t)} }$$ Using Mathematica notations
$$I=E\left(t\left|b^2\right.\right)-F\left(
   t\left|b^2\right.\right)$$ Make $t=\sin^{-1}(x)$ and use the bounds.
$$J=\int_0^a \frac{-b^2 x^2}{\sqrt{(1 - x^2)(1 - b^2 x^2)}} \, dx=E\left(\sin^{-1}(a)|b^2\right)-F\left(\sin
   ^{-1}(a)|b^2\right)$$
